# Spring Data JPA multiple one to many relations from primary key as a foreign key

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on tinder-like Spring Boot and Angular web app, but stuck at making relationship in JPA (I've done relations in postgreSQL database in pgAdmin)
I tried @OneToMany, @JoinColumns and other methods, but can't figure out how to make it and if making relationship like this is even possible, because I hadn't found example like this on any site (including Stackoverflow of course)

When one person swipe right another person application will insert into Swipes

- id: id
- decision: yes/no
- swipeFrom: id of profile who sent like (profiles.id)
- swipeTo: id of profile who gets like (profiles.id)
- timestamp: timestamp

AND IN EVERY OTHER TABLES IT WILL WORK LIKE ABOVE

**Is relations like this possible?**
If not, what should I do? Maybe just left it like it's and just delete Matches, Swipes etc. manually in method when parent is deleted?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know what you've tried, but it is possible. If you want bidirectional mapping, you would have:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "profiles")
public class Profile {

    // other fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sender", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Message> sentMessages = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Message> receivedMessages = new ArrayList<>();

    // other collections for swipes, matches and timers
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "messages")
public class Message {

    // other fields

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "message_from")
    private Profile sender;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "message_to")
    private Profile receiver;
}
```

The same applies for other tables (swipes, matches, timers). You use `@JoinColumn` to specify which foreign key you want to map to which field.

If you want unidirectional mapping or something else, I encourage you to check [Vlad Mihalcea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025118/vlad-mihalcea)'s article [The best way to map a @OneToMany relationship with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

---

**Note**: You'll need to use Criteria API (or some other approach) if you want to fetch Profile with sent and received Messages. If you would try something like:

```java
@Query("from Profile p join fetch p.sentMessages join fetch p.receivedMessages where p.id = :id")
Optional<Profile> findProfileByIdFetchSendAndReceivedMessages(int id);
```

or

```java
@Override
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "sentMessages", "receivedMessages" })
Optional<Profile> findById(int id);
```

you would get [`MultipleBagFetchException`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/loader/MultipleBagFetchException.html).

Since there are many great articles on this topic, I will not go into details now. For example, you can check another [Vlad Mihalcea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025118/vlad-mihalcea)'s article [The best way to fix the Hibernate MultipleBagFetchException](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/) if you ran into this issue.